# How can i simulate a gnosis-safe transaction?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

I have been testing and simulating transactions for quite some time using tenderly.

However, for a specific smart contract that calls another contract which has a modifier that requires the caller to be the owner, simulating becomes tricky because the owner if equal to the gnosis-safe address can only be properly tested if the simulated call is originated from the actual safe contract using DELEGATECALL.

I would like to know:

- Is there an easy method to create a mock/test safe transaction and then plug it into tenderly?
- or should I create a testing contract that simply DELEGATECALLs arbitrarily to my desired contract like the GnosisSafeProxy does, bypassing the execTransaction?

ps: on tenderly it doesn't know the originating *From* address is a safe when doing a simulation. It assumes it's always an EOA.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed tricky and not really possible with Tenderly right now. You can only simulate it as soon as you have all but the last confirmation. In this case the last confirmation can be simulated using the `from`.

We will be working on improving this with Tenderly until then you would have to use other tools.

[Safe Ape](https://github.com/banteg/ape-safe) is a python tool that allows you to do this written in Python and [Safe Simulator](https://github.com/rmeissner/safe-simulator-gh-action) a github action do to the simulation via on GitHub. (See https://github.com/safe-demo/safe-actions-demo-mainnet for an example).

Comment: Any updates so far?